# Edit startup screen in JMonkey Engine

Tags: splash-screen, java, jmonkeyengine

I want to edit the startup screen of a default JMonkey project so I can replace the image which shows the JMonkey with a custom image (our project logo). I mean the screen which appears when you execute a `SimpleApplication` project.
I'm running the JMonkey SDK on a Linux Machine (Linux Mint 13 if that matters) and with OpenJDK 7.

Comment: Maybe you could add your solution to a self-answer and mark as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the appsettings in the main method before app.start. To do so, firstly import `com.jme3.system.AppSettings;`, then create a new `AppSettings` object with the parameter true or false, after that you can specify the location of the new image via `yourAppSettingsObject.setSettingsDialogImage(path/to/image)`.

To set these settings as the settings for your App object, type `app.setSettings(yourAppSettingsObject);`.

Comment: I've posted the solution that you put in your question as an answer (**it is perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question**, in general post it as an answer however). As this is community wiki I will gain no reputation for your work. However if you wish to repost this solution as your own answer I will delete this.